# How to stretch a listBoxItem in a WPF view?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

I am trying to write a WPF application using c#.

I am using [Modern UI for WPF](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui) to style my window.

I have a view where I need to show a label in one column and a text box in a second column in a `ListBox` For some reason I can't seems to stretch the items. As you can see, I am using `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` which many hits out there suggest to do. I even tried adding `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` to the `ListBox` with no luck.

Here is the `XAML` code of my view

```
<GroupBox Header="Groups">

        <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding GroupItems }">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Title}"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Padding="0 0 7 0"
                               Margin="0,6,0,3" />

                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=Amount, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</GroupBox>
```

Here is a screenshot of how it looks like.
[image]
[image]

How can I stretch the items to take up the whole space with in the `GroupBox`

I want the `Label` to take 1/3 or the `GroupBox` and the `TextBox` to take the other `2/3` of the same `GroupBox`

Comment: Indeed, works fine.  Prove this to yourself by putting above code into a empty WPF app.  So style police is assaulting you from elsewhere.  A fairly common issue in WPF.

Comment: @AQuirky Indeed it works. It turned out that something in the `Modern UI for WPF` that I am using.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked that part.  So I installed Modern UI in my test bench and still it works fine.  What am I missing?  The UI seems to look the same.  Do I need to flip a switch somewhere?

Comment: @AQuirky not really sure. I switched to using MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit and everything seems to be working as expected.